# Solutions to $AX=B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is my proof of the following statement correct?

Claim. Let $M^\prime=[A|B]$ be a reduced row echelon matrix. Then $AX=B$ has solutions iff there is no pivot in the last column $B$.

My proof. If there is a pivot in the $i^{th}$ row then it looks like: $\text{row }i=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0& 0 \dots&0&|&1\end{bmatrix}$. This means that $0=1$ which is a contradiction. So the system has no solutions if there is a pivot in some row. Conversely, if there is no pivot in $B$, then: $$x_i=b_i-\sum_{j\gt i}a_{ij}x_j, \forall i$$. So the system has solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the pivot is the *first non-zero entry in the row* (when looking from left to right). After row reducing, the all the pivots are $1$. Clearly, the number of pivots must be less than or equal to the number of rows. If it is less, then there are rows with *no pivot* (basically a row of $0$'s in the left side of the augmented matrix) which is the situation you mentioned in your second paragraph. In this case, if the corresponding entry in $B$ is not $0$, then we get the contradiction that you stated. So $AX = B$ has solutions if and only if all the entries in $B$ in the rows containing no pivot is $0$.